# Calling onCreateOptionsMenu() from multiple views

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

This may be because of my lack of full understanding of how java works. Still learning!

Let's say we have an activity, with onCreate code.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new GameMainView(this));
    }
}
```

We've got our view now. My question is this. There are subroutines in both the GameActivity class and the GameMainView class that I want to call using the responses from onCreateOptionsMenu(). How would I get access to both those classes? I know that I could create an abstract class specifically for onCreateOptionsMenu() and have GameActivity and GameMainView override it to perform what they need. Is this the only option? Does onCreateOptionsMenu() only get called once? And if so, where? If I override it all over the place, will they all get executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your Activity like this:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private GameMainView gameMainView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameMainView = new GameMainView(this);
        setContentView(gameMainView);
    }
}
```

Then in your method which handles the selected menu option you can deal with the selection in the activity, and forward it on to the view too.

Comment: Do you think this is the best way to handle the options menu system in a 1-activity many-views app? When you use 'super', does that basically run all the code in the superclass's onCreate? (using your snippet as an example)

Comment: Yes it'll be fine. And yeah, calling `super` will run the code in the parent class. In Android sometimes you are required to invoke super, like in the `onCreate` method of an `Activity`. Other times, it's up to you depending on what you have overridden.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've put it to use already, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can only override it in your activity class. Keep a reference to GameMainView in the activity and call methods in the view when buttons are pressed.